# использовать цикл в шаблонах WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Итак, я создал отдельный шаблон меню из 4 пунктов. Каждый пункт включает в себя выпадающие списки, наводишь курсор на пункт и список выпал и т.д. При создании новой страницы в ВордПресс я использую скрипты подключения get_header.php и get_footer.php. После скрипта get_header я подключаю шаблон get_tempalate_part('blue-menu'). Как мне нужно использовать цикл, чтобы сработал функционал выпадающего списка? В functions.php зарегал blue-menu, пробовал скрипт js написать. Работать не хочет, но само меню видит, то есть на странице присутствует это меню из 4 горизонтальных пунктов, но выпадающего меню нет...

Comment: Какой-такой "шаблон меню"? причём тут цикл..  А нормально меню почему не сделать?

Comment: Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve